# Cornerstone Tools in ReactJS - not working on first load bit works afterwards

Tags: javascript, reactjs, medical, cornerstonejs

I'm trying to load the latest [cornerstone tools](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneTools) in ReactJS, but I can't get it to work. I can load cornerstoneJS, and then display the image, but the will not be activated. I have seen examples working using older versions of cornerstonejs react, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3vyk462z5) and [here](https://shalkam.github.io/react-cornerstone-example/), but once updated they stop working too.

Here is my code:

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import CornerstoneElement from "./cornerstoneElement";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Cornerstone React Component Example</h2>
    <CornerstoneElement imageId="https://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad16rgb.png" />
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**CornerstoneElement.js**

```
import React from "react";
import * as cornerstone from "cornerstone-core";
import * as cornerstoneMath from "cornerstone-math";
import * as cornerstoneTools from "cornerstone-tools";
import Hammer from "hammerjs";
import * as cornerstoneWebImageLoader from "cornerstone-web-image-loader";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const defaultTools = {
  Pan: 2,
  ZoomMouseWheel: 0,
  Wwwc: 1
};

cornerstoneTools.external.cornerstone = cornerstone;
cornerstoneTools.external.cornerstoneMath = cornerstoneMath;
cornerstoneTools.external.Hammer = Hammer;
cornerstoneWebImageLoader.external.cornerstone = cornerstone;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    color: "black",
    position: "relative"
  },
  bottomLeftStyle: {
    bottom: "0.5rem",
    left: "0.5rem",
    position: "absolute",
    color: "white"
  },
  bottomRightStyle: {
    bottom: "0.5rem",
    right: "0.5rem",
    position: "absolute",
    color: "white"
  }
});

class CornerstoneElement extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      viewport: cornerstone.getDefaultViewport(null, undefined)
    };
    this.toolBox = {};

    this.onImageRendered = this.onImageRendered.bind(this);
    this.onNewImage = this.onNewImage.bind(this);
    this.onWindowResize = this.onWindowResize.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        className={[classes.root, "viewportElement"].join(" ")}
        ref={input => {
          this.element = input;
        }}
      >
        <canvas className="cornerstone-canvas" />
        <div className={classes.bottomLeftStyle}>
          Zoom: {this.state.viewport.scale}
        </div>
        <div className={classes.bottomRightStyle}>
          WW/WC: {this.state.viewport.voi.windowWidth} /{" "}
          {this.state.viewport.voi.windowCenter}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onWindowResize() {
    cornerstone.resize(this.element);
  }

  onImageRendered() {
    const viewport = cornerstone.getViewport(this.element);

    this.setState({
      viewport
    });
  }

  onNewImage() {
    const enabledElement = cornerstone.getEnabledElement(this.element);

    this.setState({
      imageId: enabledElement.image.imageId
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const element = this.element;
    this.loadDefaultCanvas(element);

    this.element.addEventListener(
      "cornerstoneimagerendered",
      this.onImageRendered
    );
    this.element.addEventListener("cornerstonenewimage", this.onNewImage);

    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onWindowResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    const element = this.element;
    element.removeEventListener(
      "cornerstoneimagerendered",
      this.onImageRendered
    );

    element.removeEventListener("cornerstonenewimage", this.onNewImage);

    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onWindowResize);

    cornerstone.disable(element);
  }

  loadDefaultCanvas(element) {
    //enable element
    cornerstone.enable(element);
    this.loadImageToGivenPath().then(() => {
      cornerstoneTools.init();
      console.log(cornerstoneTools);
      this.loadDefaultTools(element);
    });
  }

  async loadImageToGivenPath() {
    let image = await cornerstone.loadAndCacheImage(this.props.imageId);
    return cornerstone.displayImage(this.element, image);
  }

  loadDefaultTools(element) {
    for (const defaultTool of Object.keys(defaultTools)) {
      this.loadCsTool(
        String(defaultTool),
        defaultTools[defaultTool],
        true,
        element
      );
    }
  }

  loadCsTool(toolName, toolMouseMask = 0, activate = false, element) {
    const tool = cornerstoneTools[toolName + "Tool"];
    cornerstoneTools.addToolForElement(element, tool);
    //keep toolbox status
    this.toolBox[toolName + "Tool"] = {
      isEnabled: false
    };
    if (activate) {
      this.activateCsTool(toolName, toolMouseMask, element);
    }
  }

  activateCsTool(toolName, toolMouseMask = 0, element) {
    cornerstoneTools.setToolActiveForElement(element, toolName, {
      mouseButtonMask: toolMouseMask
    });

    this.toolBox[toolName + "Tool"].isEnabled = true;
  }
}

CornerstoneElement.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CornerstoneElement);
```

However, I just noticed that when I put the code in a [fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/cornerstone-react-component-example-2iw8m), it works fine after breaking the code at some point, and fixing it immediately. However it does, not work on page load, which is the expected outcome.

The image link is passed as props to the cornerstoneElement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: fiddle now works with external image, issue persists. There is no error or warning in the console.

Comment: Your code seems to have so many issues related to `this` in your React component and method declaration. Does not solve your issue but the thing I wanted to point out. convert all methods to arrow functions and remove all the bind's

Comment: Thank you, i do understand this `this` issue, this is code i copied from the example i linked and forked to the fiddle, just didn't want to change it to understand the issue. I have figured it out and i will add an answer soon. And thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've asked your question, the Cornerstonejs Core team has released a practical example of wrapping Cornerstone and Cornerstone Tools version 4 in a React component:

https://github.com/cornerstonejs/react-cornerstone-viewport